# What do university professors expect when interviewing a high school student for an internship opportunity? What are some tips?

Tags: interview, internship

I have been invited to an online meeting with a professor next week to discuss a year-long internship opportunity. What would the professor ask during the interview? And what kind of questions should I prepare?

Comment: What field is this for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:) It's about nanoengineering.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on the interview!

For the most part these sorts of interviews are context specific. Questions depend on the Professor and the position. But there are at least two connected topics that will probably come up: 1. How will you use this internship to develop yourself towards your goals for the future (or what do you hope to get out of it); 2. What do you bring to the role (or what can you contribute).

If you have good answers ready for those, you are going to come off as prepared.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! (He is an assistant professor in nanoengineering by the way)